# Subscribe to messages published by NServiceBus 2.5 endpoint from NServiceBus 4.7.5 endpoint

Tags: nservicebus

I have two endpoints, one is NSB 2.5 and publishes messages, and one is NSB 4.7.5.  I want to subscribe to the events published by NSB2 in my NSB4 endpoint, however when I add the subscription to the NSB4 endpoint I get the following error in the NSB2 endpoint:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.MessageSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream) in c:\dev\v3\NServiceBus\src\impl\Seri
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport.Extract(Message message) in c:\dev\v3\NServiceBus\src\impl\uni
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport.ReceiveFromQueue() in c:\dev\v3\NServiceBus\src\impl\unicast\N
```

And the following in my NSB2 error queue:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfHeaderInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>NServiceBus.MessageId</Key>
    <Value>7ffbe1e3-9b2c-456c-bcb7-a43d011a2389</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>NServiceBus.CorrelationId</Key>
    <Value>7ffbe1e3-9b2c-456c-bcb7-a43d011a2389</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>NServiceBus.OriginatingEndpoint</Key>
    <Value>NSB4Client</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>$.diagnostics.originating.hostid</Key>
    <Value>75e8656bb268f44ded5f2a82b8798e6a</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>NServiceBus.MessageIntent</Key>
    <Value>Subscribe</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>NServiceBus.Version</Key>
    <Value>4.7.5</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>NServiceBus.TimeSent</Key>
    <Value>2015-02-12 17:07:14:158882 Z</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>NServiceBus.OriginatingMachine</Key>
    <Value>xxx</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>NServiceBus.ControlMessage</Key>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
  <HeaderInfo>
    <Key>SubscriptionMessageType</Key>
    <Value>MyMessages.EventMessage, MyMessages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</Value>
  </HeaderInfo>
</ArrayOfHeaderInfo>
```

I'm assuming it is because the headers are incompatible between 4 and 2 in which case I should be able to use a mutator to convert to a compatible format, howeverI tried using a mutator to intercept the outgoing message on the NSB4 endpoint but it doesn't seem to intercept the message (using both IMutateTransportMessages and IMutateMessages)

**Update 2015-02-16**
It appears that the outgoing mutators for subscriptions was disabled in 4.3 according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/XVLQkCouKCk That would explain why my outgoing mutator solution does not work

Comment: NServicebus is backwards compatible (not forward) so you could probably achieve this the other way around... 
There might be a bug with message mutators. I'm trying to verify and will let you know

Answer (score 1):

V2.5 expects the messages to be wrapped in a root node even though there is just one message beeing sent. That setting is off by default in v4.

Turn it on by calling:

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/4.7.5/src/NServiceBus.Core/Settings/SerializationSettings.cs#L11

Comment: Thanks @Andreas looks like what I want however I can't seem to get it to work.  Doing this:

`public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        
            public void Init()
            {
                Configure.Serialization.Xml().WrapSingleMessages();
            }
        
    }
`
And I'm still getting the error, am I configuring it wrong? (Sorry about the formatting)

Comment: Does the xml payload contain a wrapping `<Messages>` element if you look at the raw message arriving to the v2.5 endpoint?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, this is what I'm seeing arriving in the queue: http://pastebin.com/ZtFRtBzK

Comment: Is that really the body of the message? (looks like the headers)

Comment: The body is empty actually, size is 0 bytes.  No idea why that is the case.  What should the subscription message body normally look like?

Comment: That seems to be the subscription message that subscribers sends to publishers. Unfortunately v4 are not compatible in that regards since the intentenum was changed. Since v2 doesn't have message mutators the only way around this I can think of is to add the subscription manually to the subscription storage. Which storage type are you on? (msmq or nhibernate?)

Comment: Our 2.5 endpoints are using MSMQ storage, we're using DB on our 4 endpoints

Comment: Ok, you should be able to insert the subscription straight into the database to make sure you v4 endpoint gets subscribed. The issue is then that everytime the v4 endpoint restarts it will autosubscriber again causing that control message to fail at the v2.5 endpoint. You can either: 1. Live with it. 2: Turn off autosubscription for your v4 endpoint. 3. Remove the message mapping for that specific event from the app.config of the v4 endpoint.